# php - Initiate constructor

Tags: php

If I have a class with only static methods, what is the best way to initialize the constructor in that class, for example:

```
Class Example {
    public function __construct(){
        /*code here*/
    }
    public static function method1()
        /*code here*/
    }
    public static function method2() {
        /*code here*/
    }
}

Example::method1();
```

The constructor didn't get initiated, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: @user3540050 When static notation like `Example::method1()` became deprecated? Any proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the whole solution is bad, you can have a private static method which is called in each other public static method.

This is not a constructor, and it's normally, because the constructor is used to construct and object, and you don't have one in static context.

So, for firing a common functionality after each static call, you can use:

```
class Example {
    private static function common() {
        echo 'called';
    }
    public static function method1() {
        self::common();
        echo "</br> method1;";
    }
    public static function method2() {
        self::common();
        echo "</br> method2;";
    }
}

Example::method2();
```

Which results into

```
called
method2;
```

You can also build your object into the static method

```
class Example {
    private function __construct() {
        echo 'contructor called';
    }
    public static function method1() {
        $self = new self();
        echo "</br> method1;";
    }
    public static function method2() {
        $self = new self();
        echo "</br> method2;";
    }
}

Example::method1();
```

Results into:

```
contructor called
method1;
```

The problem here is that each method will can new instance of the constructor.

You can use the Singleton pattern as suggested, in order to have shared instance of the class in all your static methods.

```
class Example {

    private static $_inst = null;

    private $_x = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        echo 'contructor called';
    }

    private static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$_inst == null) {
            self::$_inst = new self();
        }
        return self::$_inst;
    }

    public static function method1() {
        self::getInstance();
        self::getInstance()->_x = 100;
        echo "</br> method1;";
    }
    public static function method2() {
        self::getInstance();
        echo self::getInstance()->_x;
        echo "</br> method2;";
    }
}

Example::method1();
Example::method2();
```

Which will result into:

```
contructor called
method1;100
method2;
```

So the value of instance variable `$_x` is saved when `method2()` is called, but the constructor is not called second time as you can see there is only one `contructor called` in the result.

And, to repeat myself, this whole idea is horrible.

Comment: @MarinescuEdward hope it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could call your class as a singleton:

```
class myClass
{
    private static $_instance;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
        // Construct
    }

    /**
     * Returns itself
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new myClass();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

Call it like: 
    $myClass = myClass::getInstance();

Comment: Why would he make a singleton without any reason?

Comment: He wanted to use his methods statically while still calling his construct function didn't he.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading the question again and noticed.. Damn, it's too early!

Answer (score 0):

Since the class only has static methods, `__construct` is not necessary. Declare it as **private** to prevent used as `new Example`

```
private function __construct(){
    /*code here*/
}
```

And the point is **static methods should not have state**, so you won't have to do the **initialization**.

Comment: That's not the point here. He wants that the constructor being called when he called a static method

Comment: @fluminis The point is `constructor` is not necessary for static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are called when using the `new` keyword!

Not when calling a static method

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code.

```
Class Example {
    public function __construct(){
        /*code here*/
    }
    public static function method1()
        /*code here*/
    }
    public static function method2() {
        /*code here*/
    }
}

$obj = new Example();  // Write this way or as below line
$obj = new Example;  // I think first one is better, to initiate the construct function
$result = $obj->method1();
```

Comment: You should remove the `static` keyword if you access the method using `->`

Comment: Than is no point in creating static methods in this case, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new instance of the class and call the static methods like so:

```
$example = new Example();
$example->method1();
```

To have the constructor called.
But since the methods are static, you may call them without having an instance of the class:

```
Example::method1();
```